# Is there a better answer to this argument claiming the impossibility of time extending infinitely into the past?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time, arrow-of-time

My friend claimed that time cannot extend infinitely into the past. He explained:

> "If an event A will happen in 10 years, when do you expect it to happen? In 10 years. But if event A (such as the event of our conversation) will happen in infinitely many years, when do you expect it to happen? Never. Therefore, if time was infinite into the past, this conversation would never occur."

First, I find this argument extremely weak and totally unconvincing. Just because something doesn't make sense to us is only "infinitesimal" evidence that it is false.

Secondly, there is another issue that I find with it that I don't fully understand myself, but I have a hunch it is right. Basically in his argument he is implicitly assuming that he can pick a point P on a timeline and view any other point from the POV of point P, including points that are infinitely far away from P (which doesn't really make sense by itself). But I have a hunch that this ability to pick a specific point P on the timeline is exactly what he is trying to disporove.

Can somebody please help me understand and flesh out my own argument, and/or offer a better alternative?

Comment: From the way this is phrased, this sounds like a philosophy problem, like some relative of Zeno's paradox.

Answer (score 1):

> Numbers can not extend infinitely into the negative.
>     If I choose a number $n$ and another number $m$ only occurs infinitely later, $m$ does not really exist.
>     Now let's choose $m = 0$ and $n$ infinitely before that, we proved that $0$ does not exist.

The problem is, there is no event happening in infinitely many years.
There are events happening in $x$ years for $x$ arbitrarily large, but "in infinitely many years" doesn't make sense.

PS: And please leave nonstandard natural numbers out of this ;)

Answer (score -2):

The problem with this is that you can't go back infinite years into the past because *there was a beginning of time*, which is of course the big bang. Also, if there was a beginning of time, then it must be an end of time.

Therefore, talking about infinity is not possible in the time reference frame.

Comment: I don't understand why "there was a beginning of time" implies "there is an end of time". Also, the big bang is not necesarily the beginning of time. The justification for that statement is provided by general relativity I think, but we know GR is an incomplete theory.

Comment: Time is just another dimension, the same way a rod has a beginning and an end, so does time. This is also provided by multiple quantum theories

Comment: Why does it have to be finite if its a dimension? It is not known if the  dimensions of space are finite for example. Which quantum theories provide that time has a beginning and an end? I've never heard of such theoris.